# force instantiation of xaml resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's consider a WPF application with the following XAML (App.xaml):

```
<Application
  x:Class="My.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:my="clr-namespace:My.Namespace;assembly=My.Assembly"
  ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
  >
  <Application.Resources>
    <my:NotificationIcon x:Key="notificationIcon" ApplicationExit="notificationIcon_ApplicationExit" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        FindResource("notificationIcon");
    }

    void notificationIcon_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

It looks as if the notificationIcon resource is not being instantiated until I call this code:

```
FindResource("notificationIcon");
```

in OnStartup() method. Is there any possibility to write XAML in such a way that this FindResource() call is not needed and that object is instantiated automatically?

Comment: Don't put stuff into resources which does not belong into resources. What is your `Test` thing, what does it do and why do you need it up front?

Comment: It is main UI of my application, but not a Window/Page. Basically it is a component that displays an icon in notification area. If not in resources then where should I put it?

Comment: put it as a property or field in the `App` class (in the App.xaml.cs file). remove it from the resources and manipulate it in code as with any other field or property.

Comment: Cannot this be done declaratively?

Comment: Not sure dude, post your real XAML and code.

Comment: Updated the code in question.

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny: it can't really be put into `App.xaml` without some other code to trigger it. So just load it in code.

Comment: @user7116: but wasn't XAML meant to be a language for instantiating .NET objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public NotificationIcon NotifyIcon {get;set;}

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        NotifyIcon = new NotificationIcon();
        NotifyIcon.ApplicationExit += notificationIcon_ApplicationExit;
    }

    void notificationIcon_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

... And remove it from XAML.